# Run Configuration Error: Please specify script name IN PyCharm

Tags: django, pycharm

[Run Configuration Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlrNE.png)

i added project interpreter but code cant run

Answer (score 8):

1. Go to `Edit Configurations` on the top right.
   [Edit Configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjIYG.png)

   There you can see the `Run Configuration Error` (shown by the red arrow) and you can see the small red cross (shown by the yellow arrow).
   [Missing Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWj5l.png)
2. Then just edit your `Script path` (shown by the green checkmark) to point to the file you want to run.
   [Add Script path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wV8x.png)
3. Click `Apply` and you're done.

Sorry for the links - they are all images. StackOverflow doesn't let me add images yet.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Script path in Run/Debug configurations window. Then select the python file that you want to run.

Answer (score -2):

Goto add configuration and define a script path .It worked for me.